# create UI Test in Xcode 8 via terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Is there a way to actually create UI Tests in Xcode8 via the terminal? I am aware that UI Tests are usually created via Xcode itself but i would like to do it via the terminal and automate the whole process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use xcodebuild command to run the test in Xcode.

like:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE_NAME} \
 -scheme ${SCHEME_NAME} \
 -destination "${DESTINATION}" \
 -derivedDataPath "${OUT_PATH}" \
 test
```

do not forget to set the scheme shared.

Comment: Thank you for the input! However, i am actually trying to create a test via the terminal, and not trying to run the test.